# rails new blogs not install bundle generate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run this command it's generate error please check it

```
rails new app

  run  bundle install
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:10:in `rescue in with_friendly_errors': uninitialized constant Thor::AmbiguousTaskError (NameError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:5:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.1/bin/bundle:20:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Do you have rvm install on your machine ?

Comment: It's probably a problem with your environment (as suggested by Bharat Soni)